# Questions about callbacks in node js using node-postgres and render page

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have postgresSql with a table of users`(username, password e administrator(boolean))`. Once I make my query `(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$1 AND password=$2')` I would like to check if administrator equal to true, then redirect to administrator page, if is false redirect to the normalClient page.
I have a difficult understanding of callback. The first one can receive an error or the result, but if I receive result I need to check if administrator == true and then redirect to admin page else redirect to the client page

```
    router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=> {
      let text = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$1 AND password=$2';
      let values = [req.body.username,req.body.password];
     //callback
     //make query
      pool.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
      // if error print
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        //if receive result print 
      } else {
        console.log(res.rows[0].administrator)
        // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
      }
    });

    res.redirect('/adminDashboard');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your specefic issue, you need to move `res.redirect('/adminDashboard');` inside your `else` block. Also reading previous comments I found that you are using the `res` variable in multiple places - `router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=> {` and `pool.query(text, values, (err, res) => {`. Call the value other than `res` in either place.

Since you mentioned you are having difficulties understanding callback, here is a little intro. Whenever you execute a function in Javascript, you need to check if that function is running synchronously or asynchronously. If async, like the function `pool.query`, you need to provide a callback - essentially another method that needs to be run when data is fetched from the original method.

When Javascript starts executing your code, it will call the `pool.query` method, but it will not wait for the results! Instead it will go and execute the `res.redirect('/adminDashboard');` line of code. That is the reason why you need to move this line inside your callback.

And that is the beauty of Javascript. Having methods run async makes your overall program faster because now your thread is not sitting idle. It does not wait for the results but it goes to execute the next operation. It will come back and execute the callback function when your original method is done and has returned the data back.

## Update

Per your comment, if you rename the `res` in your pool like this, `pool.query(text, values, (err, queryRes) => {`, you can still do `res.redirect('/adminDashboard');` inside the else block because you still have access to the parent `res` variable.

Comment: I got it , but if I change change 'res'  inside pool.query in  'queryRes' , I cannot make  'queryRes.redirect()'. It is not a function of express. but of pool.query

Comment: And how can i check if my administrator is === true?

Comment: The `queryRes` variable will contain all the user information and you can check `if admin` under the else block.

Comment: Thank you so much , you make my day. I learned that I can use parent res variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to make redirect inside of callback in `pool.query` function.

Comment: I have already tried but inside callback res.redirect is not a function cause res is about pool.query

Comment: Well, you can just use different name of variables in callback of pool.query: poolErr, poolRes and res will be the variable you need